# Obtaining Rotation and Translation from 3D Hand Keypoints

Tags: computer-vision, robotics, pose-estimation, kinematics

I currently have a stable source of 3D Key points from the palm of my hand. I would like to know how I can go about getting the transformation of my hand after some random motion a few frames later.

The key points I have are the wrist, and the knuckle joints of each finger.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Anush. Would be better if you add some sample of the code that you are using at the moment.

Comment: Hey, I've been using the procedure described here http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671, the results not good at all. Is there another method to do this?